# Prevent WordPress to remove query vars from url

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have a website and in my localhost I can access page pagination through `query_vars`. However, when I upload this site to my server, it does not recognize `query_vars` and simply removes it from the URL.

For example:

`http://website.com/programacao/page/1` becomes `http://website.com/programacao/`

But on the localhost:

`http://locahost/programacao/page/1` remains `http://locahost/programacao/page/1`

And I'd like to know the reason for that. I've already tried setting up RewriteRules in .htaccess and functions.php but nothing happens.

Thanks for the help.

**aleDsz**

Comment: What is `programacao`? Note that if your permalink structure has a trailing slash, all URLs must have a trailing slash- `page/1` should be `page/1/`.

Comment: `programacao ` is the permalink of my page. I've already used with `/page/1/` but anyway, on the server, it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

My solution was change to use `http://website.com/page-name/page/1/` and `http://website.com/page-name/page/2/`. And when I get `query_var`, I decrease it and check if it is less than zero, I return it to zero.

I had to use this solution because when I pass `/page/1/` or when I do not pass anything, my `paged` returns me a zero value, and when I pass `/page/2/`, it returns me 2.

So, decrement to be in the exact position of my array and pagination through the ACF is executed successfully.